# Commented code on a JSP page gets executed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

I have created a JSP page to deal with the exceptions:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 text-center">

        <div class="messageJsp">
            <c:out value="${message}" />
        </div>
        
        
        <!--
        
        Failed URL: <c:out value="${url}" />
        Exception Message: <c:out value="${exception.message}" />
        
        <c:forEach var="line" items="${exception.stackTrace}">
            <c:out value="${line}" />
        </c:forEach>
        
         -->
        
    </div>
</div>
```

And I also have Java class that sends info about exceptions to that JSP page:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    
    @Value("${message.error.exception}")
    private String exceptionMessage;

    @ExceptionHandler(value=Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        
        modelAndView.getModel().put("message", exceptionMessage);
        modelAndView.getModel().put("url", req.getRequestURI());
        modelAndView.getModel().put("exception", e);
        modelAndView.setViewName("app.exception");
        
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

And for testing purposes I intentionally added exception to my code to test this and I'm getting all the information from the code that is commented out in the JSP page and I don't understand why or how that works so I was hoping if I could get explanation:

NOTE: After error happens I get redirected to error page and if I right click on page -> View page source I can see in the comment that my commented JSP code actually executed and provided info for me (which is great but I don't understand how)

Page source can be found here: [Stacktrace comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Plj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist **html comments** (`<!-- -->`) in which everything is executed at server side. And **JSP comments** (`<%-- --%>`) which are code relevant comments. So this allows you to output hidden info in HTML comments as result of code execution.

But it can also execute unintended code, assumed to be out-commented. The same holds for syntax errors (i.e. in JSP tags).